# Use of casts in an int expression to convert result into double

Tags: java, methods, casting

As far as I know Java has automatic casts for transforming compatible data types from smaller to larger since no data is lost, yet in one of the test programs in my JDK 8 beginners guide book, a cast is used this way.
    ***The method fuelNeeded is of question.***
    I know it prints the same double result without the cast so why is this needed? Or is it?

```
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;

    Vehicle (int p, int f, int m) {
        passengers = p;
        fuelcap = f;
        mpg = m;
    }

    int range() {
        return mpg * fuelcap;
    }

    double fuelNeeded(int miles) {
        return (double) miles / mpg;
    }

}

public class CompFuel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle(7, 16, 21);
        Vehicle supra = new Vehicle(2, 14, 12);
        double gallons;
        int dist = 252;

        gallons = minivan.fuelNeeded(dist);
        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles, minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel");

        gallons = supra.fuelNeeded(dist);
        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles, supra needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try removing the cast, and trying something like `1/2`, the return value will be `0.0`. with the cast, return value will be `0.5`.

There is a difference because of the cast - explicitly casting the variable `miles` to `double` makes the overall division a division between a `double` and `int`, this gives us a `double` value. Not casting would result in an `int` division.

Comment: You are right :)

Comment: But whats the point of declaring the method with the double type if you have to write a cast anyways, seems weird in this situation.

Comment: Declaring the method return value type is different from what you're calculating using the cast.

Assume the return type is `int`, the value returned will not have floating point values like `1`. If the return value is `double`, even if there is integer division, there will be a floating point value like `1.0`